# ChildProcess.onExit and ELIFECYCLE error while using npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

people.

I was installing a npm package called 'koalanlp' via command 'npm install --save koalanlp', and I was continuing to get the following error message.

---

> gyp ERR! build error
>
> gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:240:12)
>
> gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-20-generic
>
> gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node"
>   "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild"
>
> gyp ERR! cwd /home/fromakim/github/Korean_Sentiment/node_modules/java
>
> gyp ERR! node -v v10.13.0
>
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
>
> gyp ERR! not ok
>
> npm WARN korean_sentiment@1.0.0 No description
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! java@0.9.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the java@0.9.0 install script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging  output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!
>   /home/fromakim/.npm/_logs/2018-11-07T20_36_53_905Z-debug.log

---

And here is not end part of the log file.

---

> 470 error code ELIFECYCLE
>
> 471 error errno 1
>
> 472 error java@0.9.0
>   install: `node-gyp rebuild`
>
> 472 error Exit status 1 473 error Failed
>   at the java@0.9.0 install script.
>
> 473 error This is probably not a
>   problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> 474 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

---

And I have tried:

1. Deleting npm Cache
2. Updating npm
3. Deleting .node-gyp and retried
4. Installing Java again
5. Installing node packages necessary
6. Downgrading the node version from 11 to 10.13.0
7. Deleting node.modules and reinstalling

But neither worked.

---

I am currently using

1. node version: v10.13.0
2. npm version: v6.4.1
3. OS: Linux Mint 19

Comment: "Failed at the java@0.9.0 install script". So there's an issue install the `java` package. Try installing that manually (`npm install java`) and see what the problem is. Also take a look at the requirements for that package [here](https://github.com/joeferner/node-java#installation).

Comment: @robertklep tried...but I ended up with same error.

Comment: But somewhere within the list of error messages there should be a reason why _exactly_ it cannot be installed (the error log contains 474 lines, of which you only post the last 5). My guess is because of a missing dependency